# Matrix Determinant after row changes

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

If a $4\times4$ matrix with rows $v1$, $v2$, $v3$ and $v4$ has a determinant of $-1$, then what would be the determinant of $\begin{pmatrix}2v1+3v4\\ v2\\ v3\\ 9v1+2v4\end{pmatrix}$?

Since the first row is being multiplied by $2$, I multiplied the initial determinant by $2$, giving $-2$. Then, since the fourth row is also being multiplied by $2$, I multiplied the determinant again by $2$, giving $-4$. Since rows being added to other rows does not change the determinant, I thought the final answer would be$-4$. But this is incorrect.

Any help?

Comment: What happens if you take the original matrix to be $\operatorname{diag}(-1, 1, 1, 1)$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's true that adding a multiple one row of a matrix to a different one doesn't change the determinant, but that's not quite what you're doing here. Put
\begin{align*}
\alpha & = \pmatrix{v_1 \\ v_2 \\ v_3 \\ v_4} & \beta &= \pmatrix{2v_1 + 3v_4 \\ v_2 \\ v_3 \\ 9v_1 + 2v_4}.
\end{align*}
You can add $3v_4$ to the top row of $\alpha$ to form a new matrix
\begin{align*}
\alpha' &= \pmatrix{v_1 + 3v_4 \\ v_2 \\ v_3 \\ v_4}
\end{align*}
with $\det \alpha = \det \alpha'$. 
The result you cite, though, says that you preserve the determinant if you add a row of $\alpha'$ to $\alpha'$, not a row of the original matrix $\alpha$ to $\alpha'$. The vector $v_1$ is no longer a row of $\alpha'$, and it's not automatic that adding a multiple of it to the fourth row of $\alpha'$ preserves $\det \alpha'$. A correct computation would be:
\begin{align*}
\det \beta
  &= \frac{9}{2} \det \pmatrix{2v_1 + 3v_4 \\ v_2 \\ v_3 \\ 2v_1 + \frac{4}{9} v_4} 
  = \frac{9}{2} \det \pmatrix{2v_1 + 3v_4 \\ v_2 \\ v_3 \\ -\frac{23}{9} v_4}
  = -\frac{23}{2} \det \pmatrix{2v_1 + 3v_4 \\ v_2 \\ v_3 \\ v_4}
  = -23 \det \alpha
  = 23.
\end{align*}

More concisely, 
\begin{align*}
\beta = \pmatrix{2 & 0 & 0 & 3 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 9 & 0 & 0 & 2}\, \alpha,
\end{align*}
and so $\det \beta = -23 \det \alpha = 23$.

Answer (score 2):

Since the determinant function is a multiplinear map, your determinant is the sum of these four determinants:$$\begin{vmatrix}2v_1\\v_2\\v_3\\9v_1\end{vmatrix},\ \begin{vmatrix}2v_1\\v_2\\v_3\\2v_4\end{vmatrix},\ \begin{vmatrix}3v_4\\v_2\\v_3\\9v_1\end{vmatrix}\text{, and }\begin{vmatrix}3v_4\\v_2\\v_3\\2v_4\end{vmatrix}.$$The first and the fourth ones are $0$, the second one is $-4$ and the third one is $27$. Therefore, the answer is $23$.

Comment: Thank you very much! You are correct! But could you be so kind to explain why you split it up like that? I am not quite following....

Comment: The determinant is linear in each row (and in each column too). So, using this fact with respect to the first row, you get that your determinant is equal to$$\begin{vmatrix}2v_1\\v_2\\v_3\\9v_1+2v_4\end{vmatrix}+\begin{vmatrix}3v_4\\v_2\\v_3\\9v_1+2v_4\end{vmatrix}.$$Now, do the same thing with respect to the fourth row.

Comment: Oh I see. Thank you for the clarification.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative, since adding a scalar multiple of one row to another row does not change the value of the determinant we obtain

$$det\begin{pmatrix}2v_1+3v_4\\ v_2\\ v_3\\ 9v_1+2v_4\end{pmatrix} 
=det \begin{pmatrix}2v_1+3v_4\\ v_2\\ v_3\\ 7v_1-v_4\end{pmatrix}= 
\\=det \begin{pmatrix}23v_1\\ v_2\\ v_3\\ 7v_1-v_4\end{pmatrix} 
=det \begin{pmatrix}23v_1\\ v_2\\ v_3\\ -v_4\end{pmatrix} 
=-23\cdot det \begin{pmatrix}v_1\\ v_2\\ v_3\\ v_4\end{pmatrix} $$

Thus the determinant is $23$.